# Ecuation of Parabola from Point in vertex form

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've been recently studying parabolas and I learnt about the vertex form and what the values meant. Recently on a small test I came across this problem.

For the vertex at point **(2,-3)** find the ecuation in vertex form.

Well I simply thought It would be as

$$y+3=(x-2)^2$$

But the grader told me I was wrong, and supposedly the answer was

$$y+3=-\frac{1}{3}\left(x-2\right)^2$$

I have absolutely no clue where that 
$-\frac{1}{3}$ came from. The other piece of information I had was another point on the Parabola : **(5,-6)**

Could someone explain me where $-\frac{1}{3}$ came from I would appreciate it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general equation should be $$4a(y+3)=(x-2)^2$$ and you have to use the point to get $a$ using the given point we have $$4a(-6+3)=(5-2)^2$$ This implie that $4a=-3$ and so
$$-3(y+3)=(x-2)^2
\\(y+3)=\frac{-1}{3}(x-2)^2$$
[PRABOLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola)
Notice the importance of the constant $a$[image]

Comment: How do I exactly do that...?

Comment: $4a(-6+3)=(5-2)^2$

Comment: Nope.. Thought I had it but nope, Still can't figure out how in the world that exactly $-\frac{1}{3}$ came from.. I've already marked your answer as the correct one so I won't un-do it, but I would really really really appreciate if you cold go deeper on steps..

Comment: $4a(-3)=9\to 4a=-3$ then substitute

Comment: Nope, I've rewrote the whole thing and I'm stuck at the part of $4a(-3)=9$. I'm sorry If I seem a bit foul , but it's the first time something like this has been object of my attention , no time before had to find this using 2 different points, might be very basic for you I believe but I'm a newbie here.. When solving for a I get -3/4

Comment: I've realized that you have 4a.. I believe it's just a , as I've searched and the general form is with just a, and yes. That solved my issues.

Comment: Usually we consider it $4a$ since $a$ in this case will be the distance between the focus the vertex. My answer is true. I will edit it again.

Comment: Here is a good link [Parabola](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola)

Answer (score 0):

After some confusion the way of solving for the vertex form of a parabola as this one is ...

Point A: (2,-3) Point B:(5,-6)

Vertex Form Ecuation :

$$y = a(x – h)^2 + k$$

We'll first work the basic part of the vertex for by making

$$y+3=(x-2)^2$$

After this we realized that the parabola has a vertex on a negative y point, for this there must be a value in front of the $(x-2)^2$ as it's the one that defines it,

We'll use our previosly found ecuation to find **a** as

$$(y+3)=a(x-2)^2$$

We'll plug into this ecuation our Point B that we know it's a point on the parabola, doing so we get

$$(-6+3)=a(5-2)^2$$

After simplifying we get

$$a(-3)=a(9)$$

We solve for a

$$\frac{-3=9a}{-3}$$

$$a=-\frac{-3}{9}$$

So we end up having

$$y+3=\frac{-3}{9}(x-2)^2$$

Or a simplified version

$$y+3=\frac{-1}{3}(x-2)^2$$